# ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I try to run following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


# data import and preparation
trainData = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
train = trainData.values
testData = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
test = testData.values
X = np.c_[train[:, 0], train[:, 2], train[:, 6:7],  train[:, 9]]
X = np.nan_to_num(X)
y = train[:, 1]
Xtest = np.c_[test[:, 0:1], test[:, 5:6],  test[:, 8]]
Xtest = np.nan_to_num(Xtest)


# model
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X, y)
```

where `y` is a `np.ndarray`of 0s and 1s.

However, I receive the following error:

```
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py", line >1174, in fit
  check_classification_targets(y)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 172, >in check_classification_targets
  raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)

ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'
```

From [sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit), I see that

```
y : array-like, shape (n_samples,)
Target values (class labels in classification, real numbers in regression)
```

What is my error?

FYI, `y` is `np.array([0.0, 1.0, 1.0, ..., 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], dtype=object)` whose size is `(891,)`.

Comment: provide a glimpse of data and imports please. Why do you use numpy, you can also just select the columns of the dataframe by name. Btw, why does the test file have a different structure thant the train file. This seens odd.

Comment: This error arises if `scikit-learn` is not able to tell what type of problem you want to solve (looking at the `y` data, it will return binary, multiclass, continuous etc) .Specifically, what type of data is in your `y`? Post it here, or as @Quickbeam2k1 said, it would be more helpful if samples of complete data are posted.

Comment: I had the same problem, despite using numpy.arrays. I think the y data is a problem because they are float 1.0.  Use lr.fit(X,y.astype(int)) . I tried lr.fit(X,y.astype(float)) but I got the same error. I tried to do an Gaussian Naive Bayes model

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Your `y` is of type `object`, so sklearn cannot recognize its type. Add the line `y=y.astype('int')` right after the line `y = train[:, 1]`.

Answer (score 8):

I also got a similar type of error. I found out that my target is a non-integer type. After casting my Target variable to the integer type. Boom, error is solved

```
y = train_data['Y'].astype('int')
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Miriam ,I also got the similar error but in my case individual elements of y_pred was of type `'np.int32'` and individual elements of y was of type `'int'`.
I solved it by doing:

```py
for i,x in enumerate(y_pred):
    y_pred[i]=x.astype('int')
```

Comment: In my case it was the categorical columns inside the input dataframe. Converting them to int fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Target variable in a Logistic Regression can be of type `binary` (e.g. `np.random.randint(2, size=100)`) or `multiclass` (e.g. `np.random.randint(3, size=100)`). It may be verified using `sklearn.utils.multiclass.type_of_target`. For example:

```py
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import type_of_target
y = np.random.randint(3, size=100)
type_of_target(y)    # multiclass
```

If we look at [the source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/364c77e047ca08a95862becf40a04fe9d4cd2c98/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py#L355-L368), a target can be `unknown` type in 3 cases.

1. An array with more than 2 dimensions, e.g. `[[[1, 2]]]`. 
   **Solution:** Flatten the target variable, e.g. `y = np.ravel(y)`.
2. A multi-dimensional empty array, e.g. `[[]]`. 
   **Solution:** There is no solution here. The input data is probably not correct.
3. A non-sparse array of `object` dtype whose first element is not a string, e.g. `np.array([1, 2], dtype=object)`. 
   **Solution:** Convert to any type other than `object` before model instantiation; even converting to a list works. All of the following should work:

   ```py
   y = y.astype(str)
   y = y.astype(float)
   y = y.tolist()
   ```