# Error: Unknown label type: 'unknown'....y_train values doesn't coincide with x_train values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I had this sequence of codes

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidfconverter = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=900, min_df=5, max_df=0.7, stop_words='english')
X = tfidfconverter.fit_transform(nlistRawDocs)
```

take note at the top: max_features is 900

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train_S, X_test, y_train_S, y_test = train_test_split(X, trainDF['label'], test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

chi2 = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=500)
X_train = chi2.fit_transform(X_train_S, y_train_S)
```

with here k=500

my idea was just to used only top 500 selected best features among 900 of tf-idf result

Now the problem is the value of y_train_S, I believe it doesn't coincide with number of elements in X_train

so how will I do this?

when this is feed to

```
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, random_state=0)  
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train_S)
```

it returns an error :

> Unknown label type: 'unknown'

I understand that X_train and y_train doesn't coincide with its number only that I dont know to get the updated value of y_train_S?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and format the code with code blocks (the "{}" button)? That'll make your question far more readable.

Comment: what happens when you `classifier.fit(X_train, y_train_S)`

Comment: it returns an error : Unknown label type: 'unknown'....I believe this is the result of X_train doesn't correspond to number of target label of y_train_S

Comment: the only problem is how will i get the updated value of y_train_S after doing selectkbest

Comment: Print the examples from `y_train_S`. What kind of values does it have?

Comment: y_train_S, this is an array of 0 & 1 that represent as labels

Answer (score -1):

Putting your X_train_S data through the SelectKBest will reduce the number of *columns* from 900 to 500, but won't affect the number of *rows* in your data, so it shouldn't cause a problem with a mismatch in number of elements in y_train_S and X_train.

The error you are seeing is most probably caused by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45347800/2715465).

Comment: I figure out the problem, X_train value after TF-IDF is (1598, 900) after selectkbest X_train becomes (1598,500) now question how can i make that X_train value woul like this (1598,500), the second value should depend on value of K of selectkbest

Comment: This is the new error after feeding to rainforest Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 500 and input n_features is 900 but i try to do like this  nfeatures = 500,  X_train.reshape(1598, nfeatures) but still doesn't work

Comment: If you first use TF-IDF then SelectKBest before training your model, you need to follow this exact process in your pipeline on any new data. For example, `X_900d_vectors = tfidfconverter.transform(new_text)`, and then `X_500d_vectors = chi2.transform(X_900d_vectors)`. Finally, `predictions = classifier.predict(X_500d_vectors)`

Comment: actually it follows the process tfidf then selectkbest but my problems is the target label how will get the updated label based on your example X_500d_vectors = chi2.transform(X_900d_vectors), how will i extract the label of this X_500d_vectors, s that I can assign it to y_train variable