# The target is binary, but I get "ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'unknown' instead."

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm facing an issue in a simple ML model using sklearn KFold

I categorize my target value using the following code:

```
# Import the DB
df = pd.read_csv("DB_ML_TJA20182019.csv")
#Transform continuous target into binary
category = pd.cut(df.length,bins=[0,4,100],labels=[0,1])
df.insert(18,"length_over", category)
```

Now, if I open the csv, I can see an added column (`length_over`, the 18th column, counting from 0) with the binarized variable made by the binarization of the column `length`. Then, i save the dataset as a new file, and split it to test-validation subsets, using the following code:

```
# Save the dataset with binary target
df.to_csv(r'DB_ML_TJA20182019_multilabel.csv', index = False)

# Load dataset for ML modeling (already imputed)
url = 'DB_ML_TJA20182019_multilabel.csv'
names = ...
dataset = read_csv(url, names=features, skiprows=1)

# Split-out validation dataset
array = dataset.values
X = array[:,0:18]
y = array[:,18]
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=1)
```

However, before proceding with models evaluation and comparison, I get the error: `Out: "ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'unknown' instead."`

I also checked the type of target using

```
#Check the type of target
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import type_of_target
print(type_of_target(y))
```

And the result is `unknown`

What could be the issue? The target is binary when I open the csv, but the function get it as unknown...

dtype is int64

Comment: What is the pandas `dtype` when you read it into the dataframe from your file? You can produce this with `df.dtypes` where `df` is the dataframe name

Comment: possibly related to this?  https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/17675

Comment: Thanks, the dtype of the target is float64. I will try to convert to int64 and run again.

Comment: No way, the target dtype is now int64, but I get the same message... any thought?

Comment: I solved this problem with the hint in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346550/valueerror-unknown-label-type-unknown

Answer (score 2):

Very late to the party, but I met this error while preparing the dataset for a multi-label classification task and using `MultilabelStratifiedKFold()`.

Essentially, ensure that each label you have is a numpy array with correct data type (`int`, for example).

In my case, after performing some operations on a `pd.DataFrame`, the `y label` was a `pandas.Series` which contained `list` as elements(=labels), rather than `np.array()`.

I solved it by:

```
y = df["label_column"].to_numpy() 
y = [np.array(label) for label in y]
```