# How to debug error in Jupyter Notebook Using Python libraries for ML

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I'm doing modeling using python libraries in jupyter notebook. I'm done with the pre-processing stage and attempting to build my first machine learning models (ANN; artificial neural network, and decision tree). I've been trying to understand how to fix these error for a while, and the only possible cause I've seen is linked to data type, however, I'm not sure this is an issue in my case?
Also, the last step I have done before my attempt of building the first machine learning model is splitting the train and test using this code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, target, test_size=0.3)
```

ANN code:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(5,5), max_iter=3000)
mlp.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

the error I received as a response to the code to build my ANN:

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([0, 0 etc..
```

---

Decision tree code:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

d = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3).fit(x_train, y_train)
```

the error I received as a response to the code to build my decision tree:
`Unknown label type: 'unknown'`

#Note: All my dataset are numerals, with some converted from categories. The `dtype` for both data and target is `object`. the (X) is my data, and the (y) is my target. I also posted images of the errors for reference. Please let me know if you need more info.

Update: I converted my target/((y) into `dtype integer` instead of `dtype object` . I inserted these under the under the train_test_split:

```
y=y.astype('int')
target=target.astype('int')
```

however, it did not make a difference and I still get an error . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like your are not feeding the correct data structure to the models. Please refer to this link
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.fit

and see the documentation for the **fit()** function. You need to make sure the lengths of the arrays or matrix matches to what the function expect them to be and that the data type also matches the docs.

As for the DecisionTree I believe its also cause its in the wrong format, and I found this link
[ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346550/valueerror-unknown-label-type-unknown)

that solves the same issue.

Comment: I use the codes format before for another data frame and it worked so this is weird. My data (x) has `dtype object` overall, and consists of a mixture between `float64` and `uint8` and one `int64`, while my (y) is `dtype object ` and is consisted of just `binary (0,1)` so I'm not sure still on how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: So I actually updated both my x and y into integers instead of just y and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: @user15812289 Yeah, so basically the fix was the second link i sent for anyone interested, and no problem, happy to help :)